# Google custom search engine and partial matching

Tags: substring, match, mediawiki, partial, google-custom-search

I plugged in the [Google Custom Search Engine](https://www.google.com/cse/create/new) to my MediaWiki site. It seems to work fine. However, how do I also make it search for results using partial matching? For example: when I searched for 'loft', it returned only the pages containing the whole word 'loft', but I was also looking for the pages containing 'loft' as a substring of some words, like 'create**loft**', 'delete**loft**', '**loft**study', etc.

Comment: Could anyone please give me an answer?

Comment: https://booleanstrings.com/2021/03/07/how-to-google-for-partial-words-in-urls-osint/ claims there should be a way for a preconfigured query, but doesn't explain how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't provide such advanced search features. If you need things like per-namespace search, substring matching, regex search etc. use [CirrusSearch](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CirrusSearch), which is based on ElasticSearch.