# How to run partial word search on Google.com, and find all words containing 'John' such as 'Johns', 'Johnny', 'Johnathan', etc.?

Tags: search, google-search

I would like to find materials containing "John", such as: Johns, Johnathan, Johnny, Johnie, Johnson, etc..

I tried using `"John*" site:example.com` as google search query but the results are exactly the same as I would include a space symbol between John and *, `"John *" site:example.com`, so it returns 'John Winston', 'John Cage', and etc.

Comment: https://booleanstrings.com/2021/03/07/how-to-google-for-partial-words-in-urls-osint/ claims it is possible with Google Custom Search Engines and their examples seem to work. But they don't explain how to do it... related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220652/google-custom-search-engine-and-partial-matching